# Add space between words not line breaks in php

Tags: php, html

Hi straight forward question really.  I have a search function in php that prints out the required information from a data base.  But it prints it out as one word.  I don't want a line break...just a space between words.  I've googled and checked this forum for answers but can't seem to find any.

The code works and does as it is required but it doesn't look neat.

Instead of: ID   Job Title   Job Description   Job location   Job Category

it looks like this:

IDJobTitleJobDescriptionJoblocationJobCategory

This is part of my php code.

```
// $results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results) puts data from database into array, while it's valid it does the loop

echo
     '<p>'
     . $results['id']
     . $results['job_title']
     . $results['job_description']
     . $results['job_location']
     . $results['job_category']
     . '</p>';
```

Please note I want it in one line, not line breaks.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to echo the space like this `.' '.`

Or in your Case just replace your code with this.

```
echo
     '<p>'
     . $results['id']
     .' '. $results['job_title']
     .' '. $results['job_description']
     .' '. $results['job_location']
     .' '. $results['job_category']
     .' '. '</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '<p>'
     .$results['id'] . ' '
     . $results['job_title'] . ' '
     . $results['job_description'] . ' '
     . $results['job_location'] . ' '
     . $results['job_category'] . ' '
     . '</p>';
```